Get an IP Adress/Name of pod that responded with 5xx response on nginx-ingress
My team is running nginx-ingress in EKS cluster of version 1.11.2 (chart version 4.11.2). 
Sometimes we receive 5xx errors from services and we would like to know whether it`s possible to get an IP Address/Name of Pod that responded with this code?
Below you can see our controller config, especially for log-format-upstream:
controller:
      allowSnippetAnnotations: true
      nginxDebug: true
      logLevel: 3
      ingressClassResource:
        name: public-nginx
        controllerValue: "k8s.io/public-ingress-nginx"
      config:
        use-forwarded-headers: true
        log-format-escape-json: true
        enable-brotli: true
        hide-headers: "x-envoy-decorator-operation"
        log-format-upstream: '{"msec": "$msec", "connection": "$connection",
                "connection_requests": "$connection_requests", "pid": "$pid",
                "request_id": "$request_id", "request_length": "$request_length",
                "remote_addr": "$remote_addr", "remote_user": "$remote_user",
                "remote_port": "$remote_port", "time_local": "$time_local",
                "time_iso8601": "$time_iso8601", "request": "$request", "request_uri":
                "$request_uri", "args": "$args", "status": "$status", "body_bytes_sent":
                "$body_bytes_sent",  "bytes_sent": "$bytes_sent", "http_referer":
                "$http_referer", "http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent",
                "http_x_forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for", "http_host":
                "$http_host", "server_name": "$server_name", "request_time":
                "$request_time", "upstream": "$upstream_addr", "upstream_connect_time":
                "$upstream_connect_time", "upstream_header_time": "$upstream_header_time",
                "upstream_response_time": "$upstream_response_time",
                "upstream_response_length": "$upstream_response_length",
                "upstream_cache_status": "$upstream_cache_status", "ssl_protocol":
                "$ssl_protocol", "ssl_cipher": "$ssl_cipher", "scheme": "$scheme",
                "request_method": "$request_method", "server_protocol":
                "$server_protocol", "pipe": "$pipe", "gzip_ratio": "$gzip_ratio",
                "http_cf_ray": "$http_cf_ray", "http_cf_ipcountry": "$http_cf_ipcountry"}'

When it comes to 2xx successful response codes, I am able to see in logs of ingress-nginx below log where in "upstream" section the pod ip adress is vasisble.
However, when I expressly broke some service so that it start throw 503 response, I see in logs that my "upstream" section is empty:
{"msec": "1724931972.946", "connection": "92169", "connection_requests": "3", "pid": "25", "request_id": "dee825cceb66df3f63fee9edb7ab9879", "request_length": "849", "remote_addr": "116.203.159.143", "remote_user": "", "remote_port": "", "time_local": "29/Aug/2024:11:46:12 +0000", "time_iso8601": "2024-08-29T11:46:12+00:00", "request": "GET / HTTP/1.1", "request_uri": "/", "args": "", "status": "503", "body_bytes_sent": "592",  "bytes_sent": "747", "http_referer": "", "http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/112.0.0.0", "http_x_forwarded_for": "116.203.159.143", "http_host": "kyverno.demo.k8sbrain.com", "server_name": "kyverno.demo.k8sbrain.com", "request_time": "0.000", "upstream": "", "upstream_connect_time": "", "upstream_header_time": "", "upstream_response_time": "", "upstream_response_length": "", "upstream_cache_status": "", "ssl_protocol": "", "ssl_cipher": "", "scheme": "http", "request_method": "GET", "server_protocol": "HTTP/1.1", "pipe": ".", "gzip_ratio": "", "http_cf_ray": "", "http_cf_ipcountry": ""}

I have already enabled error-log-level: "debug"  as well as:
controller.nginxDebug = true or false
controller.loglevel = 1 to 3 value

Found documentation here
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-common/
However, I still can`t see the pod IP address/Name that responded with 503. After enabling these both error-log-level and nginxDebug I only started to receive some messages related to nginx work itself (some messages from lua). Example of logs from debug mode, related to my service that I intentionally broke to receive 503 response:
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 http script var: "kyverno.demo.k8sbrain.com"
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 http script set $best_http_host
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 http script complex value
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 http script var: "80"
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 http script set $pass_port
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 http script value: ""
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 http script set $proxy_alternative_upstream_name
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 rewrite phase: 4
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 lua rewrite handler, uri:"/" c:1
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 code cache lookup (key='rewrite_by_lua_nhli_0b5957293aadfec043f3de317a2f03cb', ref=8)
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 code cache hit (key='rewrite_by_lua_nhli_0b5957293aadfec043f3de317a2f03cb', ref=8)
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 lua creating new thread
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 lua reusing cached lua thread 00000515BDB1CBA0 (ref 2)
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 lua reset ctx
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 http lua finalize threads
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 add cleanup: 0000FFFF8D70D0D0
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 lua run thread, top:0 c:1
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 add cleanup: 0000FFFF8D70D1B0
2024/08/29 12:34:16 [debug] 26#26: *1096 lua exit with code 503

So my question: Is it possible to configure ingress-nginx somehow to start seeing a Pod IP Adress/Name that responded with 5xx response?
Thanks in advance for your help!
